# ∞ gets converted to âˆž when inserted into MySQL table

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, utf-8, encodeuricomponent

The infinity (`∞`) symbol gets converted to `âˆž` when it is inserted into my MySQL table by a PHP script, but if I insert it directly from phpMyAdmin, it inserts correctly.  The symbol is passed to the PHP script by a GET call with the JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent()` around the contents.  The field in the MySQL database is `utf8_swedish_cl`.  How do I get `∞` to insert as `∞` into the database?

Comment: I know this has not much to do with the answer but just to point out, when you retrieve the data, it will be in the correct format/correctly encoded.

I guess it's just the way MySQL likes to represent non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this real good SO answer: **[UTF-8 all the way through…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)**

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* that phpMyAdmin is doing it right? `âˆž` Looks a lot like a UTF8 character stored in a latin-1 column.

What do you get when you do this `select hex(column_name) from the_table`?

- If it's `E2889E`, then your connection is UTF8, your column may not be.
- If it's `C3AC`, then your connection is latin-1 and your column is utf8.
- If it's `EC`, then both your connection and column are latin-1

Here's a quick way to verify that the column's encoding is UTF8:

```
select 
    column_name, character_set_name, collation_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where
    table_name = '_your table_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `SET NAMES utf8` before inserting the content into the database?

Comment: That does work to insert it correctly, though it still displays incorrectly.  I'm going to use Alix Axel's answer from the link to get everything UTF-8 all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the "query" `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` at the beginning of your scripts.